# AWS CloudFormation: How to use ForEach on two lists at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Assume we have a template:

```
Resources:
  r53Zone:
    Type: AWS::Route53::HostedZone
    Properties:
      Name: example.internal
      VPCs:
        -  VPCId: id1
           VPCRegion: region1
        -  VPCId: id2
           VPCRegion: region2
```

I want to add VPC IDs and proper regions to parameters like this:

```
Parameters:
  VpcIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>
    Description: Comma-separated list of IDs of VPC
  VpcRegions:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: Comma-separated list of regions for those VPC. Lengths must match.
```

I want to change `r53Zone` resource to use values from the new parameters in the `VPCs` list, but the length of the parameters is not known in advance.

I thought about new `Fn::ForEach` function but [looks like](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach-example-resource.html) it does not uses indices at all so I can't refer value in the second list whilst looping over the first one.

Also I thought about `Fn::Length` + `Fn::Select` ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-length.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html)) but cannot figure out if it's possible.

You can add another parameter like "ListsLength" if it helps.

How can I do it?